# JWT does not expire

Tags: identityserver4, jwt, ef-core-3.0

I'm using Identity Server 4 for authentication and to generate JWT with efCore, I have an API and a get request that is supposed to retrieve a list of data, so when i "login" using Postman a token is generated if I login again and use the first token the get request returns a 401 and the list of data although I have an AllowAnonymous on that specific action, does anyone know the reason for this behavior

**Get endpoint**

```
[HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public override Task<ActionResult<List<DataVM>>> Get()
        {
            return base.Get();
        }
```

**CRUD skeliton**

```
[HttpGet]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<List<TValueModel>>> Get()
        {
            var userClaim = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject);
            List<TValueModel> records;
            if (userClaim != null)
            {
                records = await Mediator.Send(new GetAll<TModel, TValueModel>
                {
                    UserId = Guid.Parse(userClaim.Value)
                });
                return records;
            }
            records = await Mediator.Send(new GetAll<TModel, TValueModel>());
            return records;
        }
```

**Start Up**

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
                {
                    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;


                })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options => options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

            })
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfig.Ids)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityConfig.Apis)
                .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfig.Clients)
                .AddAspNetIdentity<User>();


            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultForbidScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Host");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.JwtBearerEvents.OnAuthenticationFailed =
                    C =>
                    {
                        C.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                options.ApiName = "api1";
            });
```

Comment: Show the related codes please .

Comment: Is this question IdentityServer4 specific or does it have to do more with ASP.NET Core routing? It seems like you're asking why an endpoint marked with [AllowAnonymous] is returning a 401 with your list. Is that correct?

Comment: @Randy yes that i exactly what i was asking, i tried to explain what i did so i could shed some light on what is happening an endpoint is marked with allowanonymous if i login with 2 different users 1 after the other on postman and then try to hit the end point with allow anonymous using the first jwt i get a 401 and a list of data that is returned by that endpoint

Comment: Can you post the code associated with your controller method?

Comment: I have edited the Post to show the controller and the start up i hope this helps

Comment: Are you using 'UseAuthorization' in your 'Configure' method? If so, I may be able to explain the behavior you're seeing

Comment: @Randy yes i am using useAuthorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening here is that the AuthorizationMiddleware ([added to the pipeline in your 'UseAuthorization' call](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L30)) is setting the status code of the response to 401 before it even hits your controllers.

If you were using MVC for routing, authorization would be performed by the [AuthorizationFilter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs#L188) retrieved from your route.If you're using endpoint routing, which seems more likely since you mentioned that this was an api, the [AuthorizationMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs) handles the authorization of the route (which is added to the pipeline by the UseAuthorization call).

Both the AuthorizeFilter and the AuthorizationMiddleware have mirrored logic for authorization and regardless of which one you're ultimately using, the behavior will most likely be the same.

The problematic area in the authorization logic, assuming you have an Authorize attribute set on the controller or some other authorization data configured, is the part within the AuthorizationMiddleware where an authentication is performed. It happens [before the AllowAnonymous attribute is even searched for on the route](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs#L57). This would cause any authentication-related failures to be applied even if the route is marked with the AllowAnonymous attribute.

Since you have the following configured for your authentication scheme:

```
options.JwtBearerEvents.OnAuthenticationFailed =
    C =>
    {
        C.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
```

When the JwtBearer authentication scheme attempts to authenticate the user based on the token, it seems the authentication fails and results in the status code being set to 401 as per the OnAuthenticationFailed event configured above. Nevertheless, this authentication failure doesn't fail the request and the web application is still able to perform the endpoint action resulting in the returned list and the Unauthorized status code.

As to the other question of why the token is failing authentication, that would require further investigation into your IdentityServer configuration and the values used within your configuration.

This behavior of ASP.NET Core authenticating requests on routes with AllowAnonymous is also discussed here for additional context: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1577